# Dynamically change state / province in MVC based on country selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So, I know there are lots of examples out there already but I've tried most of them and still can't seem to get it to work for me. I want to choose a country that's an Enum, and then using JSON to switch the provinces with states. Right now, I can just load one or the other based on what list I choose on my view.

Model

```
    public string Province { get; set; }

    public enum Countries
    {
        [Display(Name = "Canada")]
        Canada,
        [Display(Name = "United States")]
        UnitedStates,

    }
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetStatesOrProvinces(string id)
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> stateProvListEmpty = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectList stateProvList = new SelectList(stateProvListEmpty);
        switch (id)
        {
            case "Canada":
                stateProvList = Lists.provinceList;
                break;
            case "United States":
                stateProvList = Lists.stateList;
                break;
        }
        return Json(stateProvList);
    }
```

Heler Class

```
 public class Lists
{
    public static SelectList provinceList = new SelectList(
 new List<SelectListItem>{
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Alberta", Value = "Alberta" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "British Columbia", Value = "British Columbia" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Manitoba", Value = "Manitoba"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "New Brunswick", Value = "New Brunswick"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Newfoundland and Labrodor", Value = "Newfoundland and     Labrodor" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Nova Scotia", Value = "Nova Scotia" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Ontario", Value = "Ontario" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Prince Edward Island", Value = "Prince Edward Island" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Quebec", Value = "Quebec" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Saskatchewan", Value = "Saskatchewan" },
 }, "Value", "Text");


    public static SelectList stateList = new SelectList(
new List<SelectListItem>{
    new SelectListItem() {Text="Alabama", Value="AL"},
    new SelectListItem() { Text="Alaska", Value="AK"},
    new SelectListItem() { Text="Wyoming", Value="WY"}

}, "Value", "Text");

 }
```

View

```
 <div class="form-group">
                     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Province, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label   col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Province, Lists.provinceList,  new { @class =   "form-control" })
                      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Province, "", new { @class = "text- danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js%22%3E"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js%22%3E"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
    //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
    $("#Country").change(function () {
        $("#Province").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetStatesOrProvinces")', // we are calling json method

            dataType: 'json',

            data: { id: $("#Country").val() },
           // here we are get value of selected country and passing same value
           // as input to json method GetStatesOrProvinces.

            success: function (stateProvList) {
                // states contains the JSON formatted list
                // of states passed from the controller

                $.each(stateProvList, function (i, province) {
                $("#Province").append('<option value="' + province.Value + '">' +
                     province.Text + '</option>');
                // here we are adding option for States

                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve States/Provinces.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: why have you included jQuery  twice in your page?

Comment: And what exactly happens when you run the code? What debugging have you done? "can't get it working" doesn't give us any kind of indication of the actual behaviour, or any errors you see. Please give some more detailed info to narrow down the problem.

Comment: If I run it and "Lists.provinceList" is included or the stateList, it'll display the list, but it doesn't change based on what I choose for the country. I've added a break point in my switch statement on my controller but it doesn't hit it. I also tried using int for the id for my enum in the switch statement but that didn't work either. And I added the jQuery there twice cause I didn't know which one I needed.

Comment: Have you checked in your browser's Console / Network tools for errors then? Or tried to debug the script with the JS debugger? If it's not hitting the controller then the most likely reason for that is because the JavaScript code is failing to send the AJAX request (or failing to send it correctly).

Comment: The only difference between the two jQuery files is that one (the .min.js one) is [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) - you'd normally refer to that one in a live environment where you want to save bandwidth and don't need to be able to do detailed debugging of it. And you'd reference the other one in a non-live environment. ASP.NET MVC's "bundling" features will let your code auto-choose which file to load based on the environment, rather than you hard-coding the script tags into your view.

Comment: But including _both_ of them is a bad idea and highly likely to lead to weird conflicts and script errors. That could well be the root of your issue. Remove one of them and try again. If that doesn't help, then see my comment above about using the browser's Developer Tools to debug your script.

Comment: P.S. None of what you've done really requires jQuery (unless you're still needing to target obsolete browsers, perhaps) - it could all be done quite easily with native JavaScript, which would then remove the issue of how to include the link to the jQuery file.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a lot for your help! So, on the jQuery file after the .js there was some text that wasn't suppose to be there. I removed that and then changed my enum cause I had it as a string and my country is a enum. It works now!